# Angular + Firebase Firestore authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create user (firebase firestore) with email password and fullname. But now all I can do is .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(). Is there any other function to create user with fullName?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing Firestore with Authentication.

In Firestore you have any kind of data, organized in collections and documents, and you use rules to control read/write access.

In Authentication you have users specifically for... authentication. Other users can't directly read/write authentication data of other users.

If your app is a personal list of contacts, you don't need to create a user in Authentication for every contact. Just create a user for yourself (so you can give read & write access to yourself in Firestore) and save the contacts in Firestore (in a `contacts` collection, one document per contact).

If your app has to allow users to log in and read data of other users, create your users in Authentication (just email & password, so that they can login) and also write their shared info (email & full name) in Firestore, so that other users can access it.